# other sound then the original .wav file

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm using the pic18F4550 from microchip v8.63: I used the C program language for the picdem: We created the following program: We retrieve the binary data of a .wav file converted to 8bit 8000Hz(the sound is: someone say's "red"), we write the data to the 'rom' of the picdem. Each value will be write to the port => there is a box connected to.

the problem: I can't here, the original sound (someone say's: "red") instead of that a hear a loud other sound (no noise or crackles) but a loud other sound.

That's the code:

```
unsigned int b = 0;
unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned int j= 0;

#pragma romdata const_table  = 0x1200

const rom char my_const_array[] = "0b01010101
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101001
,0b01010101
,0b01010110
,0b10100101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010100
,0b10110101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01001010
,0b10101010
,0b11010101
,0b00101010
,0b10101011
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01001010
,0b10101010
,0b11010100
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10110101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01001010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101101
,0b01010100
,0b10101010
,0b10011010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10110010
,0b10100101
,0b01010110
,0b10101010
,0b10100101
,0b01011010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b11001010
,0b10010101
,0b01011010
,0b10101001
,0b01010101
,0b01101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101101
,0b00101001
,0b01010101
,0b10101010
,0b10010101
,0b01010101
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b11010010
,0b10010101
,0b01011010
,0b10101001
,0b01010101
,0b01011010
,0b10010101
,0b10101101
,0b00101001
,0b01010101
,0b10101010
,0b01010100
,0b11010101
,0b10100101
,0b01011010
,0b11001010
,0b01010101
,0b01011010
,0b10100101
,0b00101101
,0b01010101
,0b01010110
,0b10110010
,0b10010011
,0b01010110
,0b10010101
,0b00101011
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01101010
,0b01010100
,0b10101011
,0b01100101
,0b00101010
,0b10110101
,0b01010101
,0b01011010
,0b10010101
,0b00101011
,0b01010101
,0b00101010
,0b10110101
,0b01010011
,0b00110101
,0b10100100
,0b10101010
,0b11010101
,0b01001010
,0b10101010
,0b11010010
,0b10101101
,0b01100100
,0b10101010
,0b11010101
,0b01001010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101011
,0b01101001
,0b00101010
,0b10110101
,0b01001010
,0b10101010
,0b11001010
,0b10101011
,0b01010101
,0b00101010
,0b10101101
,0b01010010
,0b10101010
,0b10110010
,0b10101010
,0b11010101
,0b00101010
,0b10101011
,0b00101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10110101
,0b00100101
,0b01011010
,0b10101010
,0b10010101
,0b01101010
,0b10011010
,0b10101101
,0b00100101
,0b01010110
,0b10101010
,0b10010101
,0b01010110
,0b10100101
,0b10101011
,0b01001001
,0b01010101
,0b10101010
,0b10010101
,0b01010110
,0b10100101
,0b01101010
,0b10101001
,0b01010101
,0b01101010
,0b10100101
,0b01010101
,0b01100101
,0b01010110
,0b10101010
,0b01010101
,0b01010110
,0b10010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01101010
,0b10010101
,0b01001101
,0b01010101
,0b01001011
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b10100100
,0b10101010
,0b11010101
,0b01010010
,0b10101011
,0b01010100
,0b10110101
,0b01010101
,0b01001010
,0b10101011
,0b01010101
,0b00101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101011
,0b01010100
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101101
,0b01010010
,0b10100101
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b01011010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10110101
,0b01001010
,0b10010101
,0b10101010
,0b10101001
,0b01010110
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b01010101
,0b01011010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b01010110
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b01010101
,0b01010110
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10100101
,0b01011010
,0b10101010
,0b10101010
,0b10010101
,0b01010101
,0b10010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b01010101
,0b00000000";

#pragma romdata

//void Delay(unsigned int);
void main (void)
{   

    TRISD = 0x00;               // PORTD  als uitgang
    TRISB = 0b00110000;         // RB4 en RB5 als ingang
    TRISA = 0x00;               // RA output

    RCONbits.IPEN = 0;          // prioriteit uit
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         // enable interrupt
    INTCONbits.RBIE = 1;        // interrupt portB aan

    while(1)
    {   
        _asm sleep _endasm  
    }
}

#pragma interrupt ISR
void ISR (void)
{

    if (INTCONbits.RBIF==1)
    {
        if(PORTBbits.RB5==0) 
        {
            TBLPTR = (short long) 0x1200;

            for(i = 0 ; i<sizeof(my_const_array); i++) {
                _asm TBLRDPOSTINC _endasm
                LATAbits.LATA2=TABLAT;

                b = 0;

                do{
                    b++;
                }while(b < 200);



            }
        }
    }   
    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you check the MAP file to check that the ROM data really ends up on datasegment 0x1200 ?

Answer (score 4):

This is an open-ended question, I won't be able to give you the absolute answer, but I can give you some ideas to try.

1. Are you sure the data is correct?  Take the array my_const_array[] and write a small program to convert it back to an 8bit wav and make sure you hear the right sound.  To me the wave data you have listed looks very short, there's only ~430 samples so at 8000Hz the sound will take around 50ms to play.  Is that correct?  As well, about half (200+) of your samples are the value '0b01010101'.
2. Try switching the bit ordering of every byte, so flip every binary value.  IE 0b01010101 becomes 0b10101010
3. Are you clocking it out at the right speed?

I would suggest you replace your recorded voice sample with something more measurable like a squarewave, and then record the output for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is probably wrong!

I suppose that you are using a single bit DAC so:

Line..

```
LATAbits.LATA2=TABLAT;
```

will copy only first (zero) bit to CPU pin RA2 the rest 7 are lost.